# Self defined ionic2 component is not found

Tags: ionic-framework, components, ionic2

I have a login component with this code:

```
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class LoginComponent {
  login: any;
  text: string;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

  ionViewLoaded() {
    this.login = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
    });
  }

  doLogin(){
    console.log(this.login.value)
  }
}
```

I try to call it from the typescript file of page using

```
import { LoginComponent } from '../../component/login/login';
```

and

```
export class QuestionsPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public loginComponent: LoginComponent ) {

  }
```

Result is:

> [13:23:46]  typescript: src/pages/questions/questions.ts, line: 17 
>               Cannot find name 'LoginComponent'.

which is the "constructor( public ..." line.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add your component to the @NgModules declarations array?

In your `src/app/app.component.ts`, add it like this:

```
import { LoginComponent } from '../../component/login/login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ..
    LoginComponent
    ..
  ]
})
```

You can read more here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#copying-your-project-to-a-new-project and here
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html